# Minecraft keeps crashing and won't launch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

When I open up my Minecraft Launcher it launches with no problem, but when I hit play, my launcher closes and then nothing else opens up. After a while, my Minecraft Launcher will reopen and say a crash occurred, this is what the crash report said: https://pastebin.com/U68A1r5k

Comment: Do you have any mods installed?

What version are you running?

Do you have optifine installed?
Have you tried to do a fresh uninstall and reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Minecraft bug. A critical even, since the game doesn't start at all. I've searched on the bug tracker and it's not reported yet. You can and should create a report at https://bugs.mojang.com. Be sure to include as much info as possible, like operating system, Java version, launcher profile arguments, …